# Problem in submitting jobs in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

A job has been submitted and an entry is also there in dba_jobs but this job is not comming in the running state.So there is no entry for the job in dba_jobs_running.But the parameter 'JOB_QUEUE_PROCESS' has the value 10
and there are no jobs in the running state.Please suggest how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NEXT_DATE, NEXT_SEC, BROKEN, FAILURES, WHAT
  FROM DBA_JOBS
 WHERE JOB = :JOB_ID
```

What's that return?  A BROKEN job won't kick off, and if the NEXT_DATE/NEXT_SEC is in the past, it won't kick off either.

Comment: After running the query with the respective JOBID, NEXT_DATE & NEXT_SEC is taking the value corrosponding to the SYSDATE i.e it is taking current date and time when the job is being submitted.The value of BROKEN column is 'N'.but again the job is not there in the running state.

Comment: Can you run the code that the job submits?  What does it do?  Does it write any log file (using UTL_FILE) or to any database table?  You're not giving me or anyone else much to work with here.

Comment: The script that I have used for the job submission is declare job_id Number; begin dbms_job.submit(job_id,'ge_b_p_ho_trf_exec;'); commit; end; The main purpose of my job is to aggregate the values of different components(Premium,claim etc) monthwise.The process also writes to a log table after the completion of each month.I have also run the job in other databases and the job is completed successfully.But this is the problem with this particular database.Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you labeled that database parameter correctly i.e. 'JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES=10'.

This is typically why a job won't run.

Also check that the user/schema that is running the job is correct too.

An alternative is to use a different scheduling tool to run the job (i.e. cron on linux)